# Duplicate a ColdFusion Session so Threads Live On After Sign Out

Tags: multithreading, session, coldfusion

I have the need to run certain blocks of ColdFusion code within a normal user's session (example: the user clicks print and I generate a PDF).  This webpage is interactive and the user get's the PDF immediately.

But I also have the need to run the same exact block of code many times within a loop (upwards of 1000s of iterations).  For this, we tell the user they will be sent an e-mail when it completes.  I spawn a `<cfthread>` with low priority and loop the same code.  The problem is that the code being ran relies heavily on variables in the session scope.  So if the user sign's out, the thread errors and dies when it hits a session var.  For the code in question, I know I could change the variables to not use the session scope, then the thread would complete no problem, but we cannot change that code.  So, I tried a hack years ago that worked, I've never felt good about it, and was wondering if someone can think of a better approach.  This is that hack...

```
<cfapplication name="backgroundThread" sessionTimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 600, 0)#" sessionManagement="Yes">

<!--- Duplicate the entire session structure --->
<cflock scope="session" timeout="30" type="Exclusive">
    <cfloop collection="#this.session#" item="session_element">
        <cfset new_session_element = evaluate("this.session." & "#session_element#")>
        <cfset "session.#session_element#" = new_session_element>
    </cfloop>
</cflock>

<cfthread action="run" priority="low" name="#this.threadid#" session=session>
  <!---
  Normal code can be included here and it will run.
  Even if the user who initiated the background process signs out.
  --->
```

So basically I create an entirely new application/session, then copy ALL the session vars over to this new application/session.  So if the user signs out it will have no effect on the background process, the code that needs the session vars will still run.

This has been working for a long time.  Occasionally I research it but have yet to find a better approach.  It doesn't seem right to me to create an application within application like this.  Is there any other way to spawn a new session **without** using the `<cfapplication>` tag?

I thought about calling `application.cfc->onSessionStart` but this is what Adobe says: *If you call this method explicitly, ColdFusion does not start a session.*  I just need the ability to spawn a new session, separate from the current user, and then copy most of his session vars over to it.

**UPDATE Feb 24, 2014:** I tried this suggestion but it still didn't work for me (test was done on CF10 box)...

```
<cfthread action="run" name="testingSession" session="#session#" priority="LOW">
    <cfset form.session = session>  <!--- add this dirty trick --->
    <cftry>
        <cfloop from="1" to="200" index="i">
            <cfscript>sleep(3000);</cfscript>
            <cfquery name="q1" datasource="#session.sv.ds#">
                select sysdate thedate from dual
            </cfquery>
            <cflog file="threadTest6" text="thread running... #i# ... #q1.thedate#">
        </cfloop>
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cflog file="threadTest6" text="error: #cfcatch.detail# /// #cfcatch.message#">
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfthread>
```

I let that page run for a few seconds, then I clicked the "Sign Out" link.  My sign out process does only this...

```
<!---End session--->
<cfset StructDelete(Session, 'dev')>
<cfset StructDelete(Session, 'sv')>
<cfset StructDelete(Session, 'act')>
<cfset StructClear(Session)>
<!---I cannot use `<cfset sessionInvalidate()>` because not all our customers are up to CF10.--->
```

When that happens I want the supposedly duplicated session that is in the thread to continue on and only the original user's session to end.  But that's not what happens.  Here is the output from `threadTest6.log`...

```
"Severity","ThreadID","Date","Time","Application","Message"
"Information","cfthread-1","02/24/14","16:26:04",,"C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\logs\threadTest6.log initialized"
"Information","cfthread-1","02/24/14","16:26:04","CMPRO","thread running... 1 ... 2014-02-24 16:26:04.0"
"Information","cfthread-1","02/24/14","16:26:07","CMPRO","thread running... 2 ... 2014-02-24 16:26:07.0"
"Information","cfthread-1","02/24/14","16:26:10","CMPRO","thread running... 3 ... 2014-02-24 16:26:10.0"
"Information","cfthread-1","02/24/14","16:26:13","CMPRO","thread running... 4 ... 2014-02-24 16:26:13.0"
"Information","cfthread-1","02/24/14","16:26:16","CMPRO","thread running... 5 ... 2014-02-24 16:26:16.0"
"Information","cfthread-1","02/24/14","16:26:19","CMPRO","thread running... 6 ... 2014-02-24 16:26:19.0"
"Information","cfthread-1","02/24/14","16:26:22","CMPRO","error: The value of the attribute datasource, which is currently '', is invalid. /// Attribute validation error for tag CFQUERY."
```

Comment: Can't you duplicate whatever in the session scope to the thread local scope?

Comment: No because the code that is being included into the thread uses `session.whatever` in 1000s of places. That's the code I was referring to that we cannot change.

Comment: Sorry the workaround doesn't work for you.  I logged the session and although everything seems to be there even after session has expired, the `session.sv.ds` is only accessible by using either `form.session.sv.ds` or `session.sv['DS']` for some weird reason.  I think it has to do with CF compiler doing optimization for session scope but doesn't work for our dirty hacky `session` in `form`.  This is Dirty for a reason, and it's just too dirty for your case.  I'd refactor the existing code if possible to not reference `Session` directly.  You can `cfparam` and default it to use `Session`

Comment: Yeah.  Oh well, I'll keep using my cfapplication hack for now.  Thank you for trying, @Henry.

Comment: If you can hack up a completely new application and copy the session data, I don't understand why you can't change the actual code to not use session. It seems that you could create a queuing system to store the relevant data and generate the PDFs from that.

Comment: "hacking up a completely new application" is just a few lines of code. I can't change the files that run in these background process cause there would be 10s of thousands of lines to change. Example: we have 1000s of files that generate PDFs for specific forms. The user can run them normally, watch it build, then get the PDF. But some process do this in mass, in loops, as a background process. Its all the same include files, and they all have `session.blah` throughout. If they would have envisioned this years prior then yes, some other variable would have been used instead of the session scope

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo, I think I just understood your confusion. My "hack" is not in all these thousands of files. It's at the very top of one file, that's all. Then all the files needed to run in the background process are included in as-is, those are the ones with all the `session.blah` vars.

Answer (score 0):

In your code that currently references session.[whatever] replace all the instances of "session." with "myStruct." and all instances of "session[" with "myStruct[". Then at the top of your block of code that needs those session variables, write this line:

```
<cfparam name="myStruct" type="struct" default="#session#" />
```

The session structure will be passed by reference (not by value) to the local myStruct variable. Any code that sets values in the myStruct will also be setting those values in the session scope. And since it's been declared as a local variable within the request, the JRE will continue to have an active handle on the structure and it won't be garbage collected (until after the request completes), even though ColdFusion may purge the session from its queue.

If you have custom tags that reference the session scope, you'll need to add this line to the tags:

```
<cfparam name="attributes.myStruct" type="struct" default="#session#" />
```

And then specify the local variable in the tag call in your loop.

If you have custom functions or CFCs that reference the session scope, then you'll need to add an optional argument to any methods that access the session scope:

```
<cfargument name="myStruct" type="struct" default="#session#" />
```

Is there anything I missed? I think those are the only things that would need to change. I don't think I have to get into the problem of the session scope not existing in the `onApplicationStart` or `onApplicationEnd` events, since you would have already encountered that problem if you were using this code in those events. So I think that should be all you need.

Even with thousands of references to the session, even in thousands of files, this can be done relatively easily. It just requires a couple of multi-file search-and-replace operations and a little testing once you're done with the modifications. I've made modifications like this before and they only take an hour or two.